# How to convert GBK to UTF-8 in a mixed encoding directory?

Tags: files, rename, character-encoding

## Background :

#### You can skip this section, if you are not interested in.

I usually backup my MicroSD card of my cell phone, with command `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=~/Document/Cell\ Phone\ Files/MicroSD_Backup/$(date +%y-%m-%d).img` after connecting the MicroSD card to my PC with the Card Reader.

There is only one partition on my MicroSD card and it's filesystem is `fat32`. And the default encoding of it is `GBK`. So, Chinese filename are encoded with GBK, while English filename are encoded with ASCII.

After I having made the latest image of the MicroSD card, I want to format it and delete some useless files in the latest image.

## Description :

The img file contains files with gbk filename and ascii filename, while the default encoding of my PC is UTF-8. I want to convert those GBK filenames to UTF-8, but I concern about those files with an ASCII filename will become garbled with running command `convmv --notest -f gbk -t utf-8 *` in the image file mounted directory.

## Question :

Is it possible to find out those files with gbk filename, and pipe their path to the `convmv` command? So, those files with ASCII filenames can survive.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `iconv`?

Comment: @Yaron It seems that `iconv` only deal with text content. I just want to convent filenames.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of GBK, so converting all of them as GBK should be fine.

Comment: Are there any other encodings? If not you could use `isutf8` from Joey Hess' `moreutils` to selectively only convert those that aren't UTF-8.

Comment: Well, sort of... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930484/change-file-names-with-find-and-iconv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @SiyuanRen 's suggestion.
`convmv` can deal with the mess situation keeping ascii unchanged which avoid being garbled.

Command `convmv -f gbk -t utf8 *` works fine under this circumstance.

By the way, another solution is use `-o loop,utf8` while mounting image files, or just use `udisksctl` which can automatically deal with filename encoding.

P.S. the whole way to use `udisksctl` is

```
# losetup --fine --show /path-to-img-file
$ udisksctl -b /the-loop-file-showed-after-former-command
```

Then, input your account's password, and it will show you where it is mounted/